# Does SE's search engine support punctuation?

Tags: support, search

I've searched a few StackExchange sites for questions/answers concerning the `??` operator in [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail).  I'm not having much luck, but I can't tell whether that's because no pages mention that symbol or because searching for punctuation is not supported.

- Do any/all StackExchange sites support searching for punctuation?
- If so, is there a Help section or FAQ about how to format such searches?

Comment: Nope, the SE search engine is pretty bad at that.

Comment: Maybe [symbolhound](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters) can do what you need: http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: @rene Looks promising. Searching for operators in SE's engine or google usually yields poor results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as it's in code, there is an easy way to search for it. Just use the ([undocumented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675)) "code" operator:

> [`procmail code:"??"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=procmail+code%3A%22%3F%3F%22)

If that fails, there is [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) (if you know SQL) or external sites such as [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/).

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).